# How to change a default widget in the Django admin?

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm using the auto-generated Django admin for my project. Here's the result:

[image: Result]

For the field "Professor", Django automatically generated a drop-down list, but there are at least 1000 elements in it. Therefore I'd like to replace the list by something more user friendly such as the widget used for "Referees", where you basically just type the first letters of the name and the elements appears below.

How can I modify the admin.py or models.py files to get that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add your field to raw_id fields in admin.py:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields=('professor', )

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

For that you would get a pretty search button

Comment: Nice! It's not exactly what I wanted but it gets the job done pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

[**ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides)

> This provides a quick-and-dirty way to override some of the [Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field) options for use in the admin. formfield_overrides is a dictionary mapping a field class to a dict of arguments to pass to the field at construction time.

Look at this example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

# Import our custom widget and our model from where they're defined
from myapp.widgets import RichTextEditorWidget
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': RichTextEditorWidget},
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to choose only one Professor or many professors?
The drop-down list is generated because you use something like `professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor)` in your model. ForeignKey implies single choice, but you example widget implies multiple choices. So your intention is not quite clear.
With the drop-down list you can also choose options by typing first letters.